# Call a function in SAPUI5 from ODataModel

Tags: odata, sapui5

How to call a function  in SAPUI5 from ODataModel object? I want to get the collection from the returned data result that I implemented as a SAP oData service. I tried to `ODataModel.callFunction` method and try to debug from browser but it doesn't work!

This is the code i used:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel('/sap/opu/odata/sap/zqud_first_service_srv/');
        oTable.setModel(oModel);
        oTable.bindRows("/EmployeeSet");
          oModel.callFunction("/EmployeeSet", "GET", null, null, function (  
          oData, oResponse) {  
             alert("ok");  
          }, function (oError) {  
             alert("err");  
          });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally it would be useful to provide more information than just "it doesn't work". However, here it is clear: Your coding does not make any sense. 
Binding the table should trigger a GET request automatically. You don't have to do further steps. I'm not sure why you want to use callFunction, but if you read the manual you'll see that this would require the name of a function to call. It does not work against entity sets.

Comment: Yes you are right,  i want to make it manully to debug the result set , obviously i had made a big mistakes can you please send me brief example how to call it and catch the result

Comment: Just set a break point into the function **read** of the OData implementation. It shall be called automatically when the list binding is created.

Comment: The main problem that i got the result repeated, for example 3 rows hold the same data,  so i tried to call the function manually instead of using the bind and debug why i  got the result repeated.